# Laravel API Getting Blank Response

Tags: laravel

I am having trouble related to Laravel API. I am using Vue CLI 3 as well. When I check with `php artisan r:l`, both routes are registered. There is no problem with the `search/{keyword}` route. The problem is a route with `download-pdf`, It can't show a response, and getting a blank response when I test it in Postman. Am I missing something?

[image]

And this is the routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'staff', 'middleware' => ['auth:staff-api', 'scopes:staff']], function () {
    Route::get('staff-management/search/{keyword}', [StaffController::class, 'searchStaff']);
    Route::get('staff-management/download-pdf', [StaffController::class, 'downloadPDF']);
});
```

And this is the controller:

```
public function searchStaff($keyword) {
    $staff = Staff::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
        ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
        ->get();

    return response()->json([
        'staff' => $staff
    ], Response::HTTP_OK);
}

public function downloadPDF() {
    $staffs = Staff::all();
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'message' => 'Previewed',
        'pdf' => $staffs,
    ]);
}
```

Response in Postman:
[image]

[image]

[image]

**[UPDATE]**
When I change to the code below, it's working. I don't know.. It's really really strange.

**Route**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'staff', 'middleware' => ['auth:staff-api', 'scopes:staff']], function () {
    Route::get('staff-management/download-pdf/{keyword}', [StaffController::class, 'downloadPDF']); 
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function downloadPDF($keyword)
{
    $staff = Staff::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
        ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%{$keyword}%")
        ->get();

    return response()->json([
        'staff' => $staff
    ], Response::HTTP_OK);
}
```

Comment: Show us your postman response and headers reaponse please

Comment: I've updated the question. Please check it out!

Comment: FYI, I am using Vue CLI 3

Comment: What does the Laravel Log file show ?  storage/logs/laravel.log ?  What does $staffs = Staff::all(); evaluate to.  It helps to use Log::info to log stuff during development.

Comment: @SeadLab, your thing is working, see the response image where you only see 1 line but white... Switch to RAW instead of PRETTY

Comment: Yes, it's working actually. I've found the problem. The problem is related with auth. When I place the route outside auth middleware, it's working. But if I place it inside the auth, it's not working. I don't know why. This only happens with route ```download-pdf```

Comment: @SScotti: I use ```$staffs = Staff::all();``` in another route, it's work. I think this is not the problem. The problem is with auth and middleware.

Comment: I've updated the code. This bugs is really really strange. Please somebody help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's done now. I removed this code:

`//Route::apiResources(['staff-management' => StaffController::class]);`

and I did manually. Now it's working.